# Amazon ElasticSearch Service Unknown aggregation type boxplot

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, symfony, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

I have created a query for boxplot in ElasticSearch 7.9.3 (via Docker image) on local with Symfony 5 and it worked just fine. But when uploading on test environment where I use Amazon ElasticSearch Service, I get error: "Unknown aggregation type [boxplot]". Version of ES is 7.9.1 on Amazon.
Code I use:

```
"query" => ...
"aggs" => [
                "agg_boxplot" => [
                    "terms" => [
                        "field" => "field_name"
                    ],
                    "aggs" => [
                        "bucket_name" => [
                            "boxplot" => [
                                "field" => "field_name"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ],
...
]
```

I have searched the internet but no answer about Amazon ElasticSearch and boxplots.

I see that Amazon QuickSight has an option for boxplots with Amazon ElasticSearch, so somehow it can be done (hopefully without QuickSight).

What are my options to use boxplots with Amazon Web Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Boxplot aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-boxplot-aggregation.html) is an XPack feature, and is thus, not available on the AWS Elasticsearch service, which is based on the OSS distribution.

The AWS Elasticsearch service only includes the aggregations in red on the following figure:

[image: Elastic subscriptions]

Source: https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions

However, you can simulate a boxplot aggregation using the following free aggregations:

- [`min`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-min-aggregation.html) + [`max`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) aggregations
- 25th (q1), 50th (q2), 75th (q3) [percentiles](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-percentile-aggregation.html)

Another thing to know is that the AWS Elasticsearch service has forked (from 7.10.2) and is now named [AWS Opensearch](https://opensearch.org/).